# MySQL with Visual Studio: Authentication Method 'mysql_clear_password' Not Supported, How to Fix?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have 2 MySQL servers I need to connect to using Visual Studio's *Server Explorer* -> *Add Connection*.

I'm setting the *Data Provider* to `MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider)` and entering the credentials, then trying to retrieve the databases. Now, with one server it succeeds and with the second it throws:
"Authentication method 'mysql_clear_password' not supported by any of the available plugins."

As far as I understand there's something different between those servers' versions and plugins. The question is, **is there a way to solve this on the client side?**

I've tried setting the environment variable: `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=1 \ Y` ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html)) and upgrading all MySQL components.

Answer (score 0):

The server is a MariaDB with PAM authentication plugin which means the **problem is on the client side** and supposed to be solved with '[MySQL for Visual Studio](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)'. Currently (version 1.2.5), this does not work for users authenticating with PAM, so the fix was to create a local authenticating user.

However, I wouldn't recommend working with MariaDB and Entity Framework because although they say the [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) is [compatible](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/visual-studio-mariadb-entity-framework-6/), it crashed for me during trying to create the model from DB.